# How execute a php file in /application folder in Codeigniter with cronjob?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need to execute a php file in /application folder. That execution will be triggered by a cronjob. The php file also will write another file in /application folder.
Why execute and write in /application folder? Because the php file will use helpers, libraries and a controller function.

I've tried the next cronjobs

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://example.com/codeigniter/application/controllers/cronjobs/CronJob.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://example.com/codeigniter/application/cronjobs/CronJob.php
```

But don't work

Comment: [Running CI From CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html)

Comment: Cronjobs work correctly, but not work when the php file to execute is in /aplication folder

Comment: Okay. Do you get any errors? You can change your command to `* * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://example.com/codeigniter/application/cronjobs/CronJob.php >> /path/to/cron/error.log` to see if the script is generating any errors.

Comment: I don't get catch errors. I use the next library to create cronjobs: [link](https://github.com/biozshock/crontab) Php files aren't executed inside of /application folder

Comment: If you have CLI access to your site, have you tried  `php <absolute path to CI folder>/application/cronjobs/CronJob.php`?

Answer (score 0):

if the cron task is running on the same machine, you can use CodeIgniter's CLI stuff: see [the CodeIgniter Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) for more info. It works quite well.

Comment: I use the next library to create cronjobs: [link](https://github.com/biozshock/crontab) It uses CI_CLI. But Php files aren't executed inside of /application folder

Comment: If you make the php file a controller then the CI CLI will be able to invoke it. You can put in a check in the called function to die if the request does not come from the CLI.

Comment: And how invoke a controller file? A controller file is a class I want to call a executable file

Comment: I believe you will find all those questions answered in the link provided above.

Answer (score 0):

by default, you are not allowed to access a file in the /application/ dir directly is my guess. You tried to open the http://example.com/codeigniter/application/controllers/cronjobs/CronJob.php in your browser? what happens?

You can't open it right? so what if you create a file outside the application folder and include the desired controller in there?